# Configuring Mono for cross compilation, what goes into --host?

Tags: c, linux, mono, cross-compiling, configure

I am attempting to cross compile Mono to run on the Moxa UC7420 device. I am at the step where I need to configure the build before running make. I have the tool chain for the UC7420 installed and I have set the CC, CPP variables to that of the toolchain. Now when I run:

```
./configure --disable-mcs-build --enable-minimal=aot,profiler
```

I get the following error:

```
configure error: cannot run C compiled programs.
If you meant to cross compile, use '--host'.
```

Now I understand I need to add the --host option to the configure command and it needs to be the information of the embedded device, but what value do I put in there? What string format does it expect?

When I run uname -a on the embedded device I get the following:

```
Linux Moxa 2.4.18_mvl30-ixdp425 #1049 Tue Oct 226 09:34:15 CST 2004 armv5teb unknown
```

Is that information useful? What do I use from there to put into the --host value?

Comment: shot in the dark, but possibly `armv5teb-linux` or a variation thereof

Answer (score 2):

Try --host=arm-linux. I usually get by with that.